# Display and filter items from multiple lists

Tags: 2010, solution

I've got a request that I'm not exactly sure how to start or solution for.

I've got say 3+ lists from *multiple* site collections. To make things easier, they're all Calendar lists with the same columns.

Here's what they want:
[image: Why do they ask for this!?!?]

They want to be able to show the items as such and be able to filter by the day, week, month, year, and calendar among other things.
Clicking on an item will bring up the SP dialog for that item *(I'm pretty sure this won't work because of cross-domain issues)*.

Here are some things I've considered:

1. Content Query
   Not going to work. Lists are in different site collections, etc.
2. Calendar View with Overlay
   I considered this, but I don't know how to modify that view. If I could turn it into tabular form and be able to apply filtering to it, I would.
3. Use the Core Search Results WP
   Most promising idea so far. I want to make sure be default, items/"results" are shown though. I'll need an initial query for it.
4. C# it up! New web part!
   Was hoping for something OOTB, but if I really have to...

So that's about it.
I know it's a bit broad, but what's the best way to go about this and are there anything I should look out for in terms of limitations, etc?

<sub>Note: Absolutely no SP Designer solutions.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1 is out of question.

Option #2 will work only in Calendar View (In tabular view it will not work)

Option #3 is the most promising and easiest option. The draw back is you need to wait till the crawl happens.

Option #4 - If you are a developer its easier to create a visual web part that can query multiple lists and display data in whatever format you want.